# Fetching data and then writing them to an array

Tags: javascript, react.js

First I fetch an instance from the database. The three functions `getSwitches`, `getSingle` and `getLinears` need the return value instance. 
When all requests are finished I want to fill the array `barFrequencyData` with the data.

How do I correctly refactor the code? Should I use `async/await` or promises in this case?

```
barFrequencyData.datasets[0].data.length = 0;
barFrequencyData.labels.length = 0;
let barFrequencyFill = [{
    label: null,
    value: 0,
}];

let myUser = jwt_decode(localStorage.usertoken);
let myInstance = 0;
getInstance(myUser)
    .then(instance => {
        myInstance = instance.data;
        getSwitches(myInstance)
            .then(res => {
                for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
                    barFrequencyFill.push({
                        label: res.data[i].name,
                        value: res.data[i].counterAmount
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return err;
            });
        getSingle(myInstance)
            .then(res => {
                for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
                    barFrequencyFill.push({
                        label: res.data[i].label,
                        value: res.data[i].value
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return err;
            });
        getLinears(myInstance)
            .then(res => {
                for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
                    barFrequencyFill.push({
                        label: res.data[i].name,
                        value: res.data[i].distance,
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return err;
            });
        return barFrequencyFill;
    })
    .then(barFrequencyFill => {
        for (let i = 0; i < barFrequencyFill.length; i++) {
            barFrequencyData.datasets[0].data.push(barFrequencyFill[i].value);
            barFrequencyData.labels.push(barFrequencyFill[i].label)
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please edit your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!